# Plausibillity of using a black hole as a telescope?

Tags: general-relativity, optics, black-holes, telescopes, gravitational-lensing

I recently learned about the proposed [FOCAL telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOCAL_(spacecraft)), which would use the Sun's gravity as a lens to observe exoplanets (or whatever it's aimed at) with incredibly high resolution. Obviously, the Sun is more convenient for this purpose than a black hole, but would it be reasonable to use the same principle to turn a black hole into a megatelescope? How would it compare to, say, a 1 AU diameter parabolic mirror in deep space?